# multiple ROC curve in R with a matrix of prediction values and labels

Tags: roc

I want to plot multiple ROC curves with a matrix of predictions and labels. I have > 100 samples with a matrix of predictions and labels for each sample. The length of the samples is different. How could I get design a single matrix for all the samples and get multiple ROC curves in a single plot? I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some example data that resembles the original data?

Comment: structure(list(number = structure(c(11L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 5L
), .Label = c("Sb.001G130400", "Sb.001G162200", "Sb.001G313100", 
"Sb.002G040300", "Sb.002G113100", "Sb.002G324500", "Sb.003G065400", 
"Sb.003G219400", "Sb.003G437600", "Sb.004G058000", "Sb.004G111000", 
"Sb.004G145600", "Sb.006G075500", "Sb.007G046100", "Sb.009G024000"
), class = "factor"), pred_values = c(0.456, 0.43, 0.412, 0.378, 
0.348, 0.428), label = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")